# red5 - start new scope from code

Tags: java, red5

Is there a way to start a new scope (room) in red5 from the application code (normally they are started automatically if a user connects to the path). I tried:

```
IScope scope = new Scope(roomName);
application.start(scope);//application is my class, extended from ApplicationAdapter
```

the call to `application.start` returns false, which means the scope could not be started (from the javadocs) but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later edit: solved - in order to add a new scope, you need to call `application.getAppScope().createChildScope(roomName);` (where getAppScope would return the application scope passed into the application in `appStart()`)